# Prioritized selection of database entries

Tags: mysql, sql, select

In MySQL I have a table that looks like this:

```
+----+------+-------+-------+
| id | code | site  | value |
+----+------+-------+-------+
|  1 |    1 | NULL  | alpha |
|  2 |    2 | NULL  | beta  |
|  3 |    2 | xyzzy | gamma |
+----+------+-------+-------+
```

The table associates a `value` with a `code`.

A entry may contain a global value (indicated by `site=NULL`) or a specialized value (indicated by `site="something"`).

I'm trying to construct a single SQL statement which, given a value for `site`, will return the specialized value if it exists, or otherwise return the global value.

With the example above, assuming I'm looking for values with `site="xyzzy"`, I want my SQL statement to return `"alpha"` if `code=1` or `"gamma"` if `code=2`.

This is, of course, easy to do with two SQL statements, but is it possible to do this with a single SQL statement?

**EDIT**

I've been asked to clarify. So I'll try:

The table is used by several web sites. Each site needs to translate a code to a value. For some codes, some sites my have their own translations; for other codes, they share a global translation. When a site looks up a code in the table, the site-specific value must be returned if it exists, otherwise the global value must be returned.

The simple way to do this is:

```
SELECT value FROM xx WHERE code=2 AND site="xyzzy";
```

If this statement returns a value, use it. Otherwise do this:

```
SELECT value FROM xx WHERE code=2 and site IS NULL;
```

Unfortunately, the software has the unpleasant requirement that the SQL statement must be stored in a configuration file that can only contain *one* SQL statement. So I wonder if it is possible to express this as a single SQL statement.

Comment: I don't see how site `xyzzy` is connected to all three records in your sample table.  Can you explain this better?

Comment: Show us the easy solution

Comment: I've edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT value
FROM xx
WHERE code = 2 AND
      (site = 'xyzzy' OR site IS NULL)
ORDER BY (site IS NOT NULL) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

The `ORDER BY` puts the non-`NULL` values for the site first, followed by the `NULL` value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a LEFT JOIN and COALESCE():

```
select coalesce(s.value, g.value)
from xx g      -- global
left join xx s -- specialized
  on  s.code = g.code
  and s.site = 'xyzzy'
where g.code = 2
  and g.site is null
```

This method has the advantage, that you can extend it, to get multiple values at once with `where g.code in (1, 2, 5)`.